# Tensor product with a dense Frechet subalgebra of the compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $\mathcal{R}$ denote the algebra of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$-matrices $a_{ij}$ satisfying
$$\sup_{i,j}i^k j^l |a_{ij}| <\infty$$
for all $k,l>0$. By picking an orthonormal basis for $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, we can identify $\mathcal{R}$ with a dense subalgebra of the compact operators $\mathcal{K}=\mathcal{K}(l^2(\mathbb{N}))$. Note that $\mathcal{R}$ is a Frechet algebra with respect to the topology determined by the family of seminorms
$$q_{k,l}(a_{ij})=
\begin{cases}
\sup_{i,j}i^k j^l |a_{ij}|&\text{if }k,l>0,\\
\|a_{ij}\|_{\mathcal{B}(l^2(\mathbb{N}))}&\text{if }k,l=0.
\end{cases}
$$

Now let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, and form the tensor product $A\otimes\mathcal{K}$, noting that $\mathcal{K}$ is nuclear. I would like to make sense of the statement that
$$"A\otimes\mathcal{R}\subseteq A\otimes\mathcal{K}."$$
It's not quite clear to me what this means. More precisely:

- What tensor product should we take on the left?
- The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220907/does-tensor-product-of-c-and-banach-algebras-preserve-injectivity-of-homo/4221227#4221227) makes me wonder whether this inclusion of tensor products holds.

But perhaps there are some nice properties that make this possible. Let me ask the following:

**Question 1:** What type(s) of tensor product would make the above inclusion make sense?

**Question 2:** If $A$ is represented faithfully on $\mathcal{B}(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$, then does $A\otimes\mathcal{R}$ have a natural representation on $\mathcal{B}(H\otimes l^2(\mathbb{N}))$?